# In XSLT, what is the difference between true() and true?

Tags: xml, xslt, boolean, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I wanted to understand the difference between `true()` and `true` and the usage of both.

For example:

I am declaring a variable `var1` as follows:

```
<xsl:variable name="var1"
    select="/root/name ='' and exists(/root/name[@as:firstname])"></xsl:variable>

<!--and now I wan to use it as a condition, say:-->

<xsl:if test="$var1=true() "> <!-- Now would I use true() or true here ?-->
    <xsl:text>Hello World</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: `true()` is a function that returns the boolean value true, while `true` may simply select a node named true (/root/name/true/child)

Comment: Thanks @sergioFC. So, in the if condition I should be using true(). I had seen code which used just true as well, so got a little confused.

Answer (score 5):

Since you have defined the variable using a boolean expression, both:

```
<xsl:if test="$var1=true()">
```

and:

```
<xsl:if test="$var1">
```

will work the same way. Not sure what you mean by `true`; it could be a node or it could be a string "true". In the latter case, the test:

```
<xsl:if test="$var1='true'">
```

would work in XSLT 1.0 (and it would work just as well with any non-empty string), but not in XSLT 2.0.

Note also that:

```
string(var1)
```

will return either "true" or "false", so the test:

```
<xsl:if test="string($var1)='true'">
```

will work the way you would expect, in both XSLT 1.0 and 2.0

Answer (score 2):

Writing something like `<xsl:with-param name="married" select="true"/>` is a common mistake (I see it more often in XQuery than in XSLT). Here the expression `true` means `child::true`, and unless you actually have elements named `true` in your source document, it's likely to select an empty sequence, which will be treated as `false()` in a boolean context.

Recent releases of Saxon give you a warning if you use the name "true" like this, inviting you to write it as `child::true` or `./true` if you really want to access an element with this name.